# How to start JSON?

Tags: ajax, json

I want to ask a question about the JSON. I am the green of the Ajax and I want to learn some JSON. Can anyone provide some links or reference to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: you could start by googling json. it returns json.org, which is the main site for learning json

Comment: If you are learning JSON you'll probably be more concerned about how to handle the data on the server side. Which language do you plan to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of resources available at the tip of the Google Search button ;) I can highly recommend this tool for helping visualize and parse JSON data.
[JSONP Tester](http://svn.coderepos.org/share/lang/javascript/jsonptester/trunk/jsonptester.html)

This is a pretty good tutorial on AJAX and JSON too. [Ajax Tutorial](http://www.learn-ajax-tutorial.com/Json.cfm)